# Invalid JSON to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm using scrapy to scrap the data from the [website](https://www.lornajane.sg/c-Shop-All?partitial=true&q=&sort=&count=1&page=20&numberOfPages=22&totalNumberOfResults=438). The website is giving me JSON and also adding HTML tags in the json values which is corrupting the JSON.
I'm using this function `json.loads(json)` to convert the json to dict in python. But this is giving me error of invalid json. I take a look on the JSON and it is invalid due to HTML's quotation `"` tags. Example is given below.

```
{"header":"<h2>Clothing</h2>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="count-text">\r\n\t\t\t\t 438 styles found</div>","refinements":"<div id="product-facet" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 filter-box top-box js-product-facet">\r\n<div class="filter-heading">\r\n<span>Refine</span><span class="clear"><a href="?text=&amp;showType=&amp;sort=">Clear all</a></span></div>\t\r\n<div class="filter-container">\r\n\t\t<div class="filter-label main-label ">Refine<a href="javascript:void(0);" data="facets-container" class="close">"}
```

As you can see that there are some `"` in the json values which are making it invalid. How I can convert this type of JSON to dict in python?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid JSON is probably generated by an incorrect generator. This seems to be more common that should be.

There is a tool, call `dirty-json` which might be of help:

https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json

There's also [an on-line verion](http://ryanmarcus.github.io/dirty-json/). Your invalid JSON is interpreted like this:

```
{
    "header": "<h2>Clothing</h2>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"count-text\">\r\n\t\t\t\t 438 styles found</div>",
    "refinements": "<div id=\"product-facet\" class=\"col-md-3col-sm-6filter-boxtop-boxjs-product-facet\">\r\n<div class=\"filter-heading\">\r\n<span>Refine</span><span class=\"clear\"><a href=\"?text=&amp;showType=&amp;sort=\">Clear all</a></span></div>\t\r\n<div class=\"filter-container\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"filter-labelmain-label\">Refine<a href=",
    "javascript": "void(0); data=\"facets-container\" class=\"close\">"
}
```

Comment: I was asking to convert JSON to Pyhton _dict_. `json.loads(dirty_json)` method solved my problem.